# How to model a temperature recording device data in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design

Trying to build a portion of a rails app that will allow users to upload a csv file from a device that contains two pieces of information, a date/time and a corresponding data point. Each unit has a unique serial number that the user will input or scan in.

I feel I'm over thinking how to model this and am stuck in neutral. Do I make two database tables one with serial numbers of units and another with data points and have a relationship that a single serial number has many data points? Or do I make one model that has all the information in one table?

EDIT:

Have been messing around with models and this is what I came up with below.

App will allow users to login and upload a CSV file that contains temperature data from a device. This data will be stored and the user can view all these downloads in different graphic formats using Highcharts.

This is what I was thinking of doing below, please let me know if there is a better way to model this. Keep in mind that each device contains roughly 200 time/temp data points and there could be 150-200 of these files uploaded each day.

Where I am getting hung up is with the temperature recorder device. One recorder has many data points(>200) of time and temp. Do I break that up into a data point table and make a relationship where a temp recorder is just denoted by a serial number and has many data points?

Given that potential volume of downloads a table for one company's temp recorders to grown by 30000 each day. Wasn't sure if in the long run this would be a black eye for performance.

Models

```
Company
t.name
has_many :temp_recorders
has_many :users

User
t.name
t.email
belongs_to :company

TempRecorder
t.point
t.time
t.temp
t.serial_num
belongs_to :company
```

Comment: Could you provide us with some example data?

Comment: Totally depends. Either way, getting all the data from a specific unit is trivial. Instead of obsessing why not just try a way and see how it works for your specific needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably overthinking it a little ;). The data you listed probably doesn't need to be split up like that.

Key Point: If you're wondering whether your fields need to be split into different tables, ask yourself

1. What relationships am I modeling?
2. Is there redundancy in the data that I could minimize by moving fields to a new table?

Consider: You have the fields data, date, serial_no. I'll assume you need the serial_no for reasons not specified here and can't just rely on the id value generated by rails on any given table.

If you keep the fields together, you have a solid basis for a model called "TemperatureSamples" or something like that. The fields in the table are tightly connected and won't have any unnecessary duplication (such as, for example, listing the collection site on every record in the table).

Contrarily, if you split the fields up into different tables, you have two or three tables named "CollectionDate", "CollectionTemperature" (and possibly even "CollectionSerialNo", but let's ignore that possibility for now). Those tables have a single column of data stored and then you have to start sprinkling in foreign keys to link them back together. Your data model has become more complex with no reduction in redundancy.

If you're just starting out with databases, consider reading up just a bit on normalization and the three normal forms (it's pretty quick reading): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization